# Font Forge - Below Base forms overlapping

Tags: font-forge

I am creating a Kannada font in which the below base forms (Vattu) if more than one are appearing one above the other.  How do i make them appear one beside the other.

This rendering is correct - ಕ್ಕ್ಲ ಚ್ಛ್ಯ - I want to achieve similar to this.

I read through the Microsoft document, but was unable to understand how it can be implemented in Fontforge - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/script-development/kannada

Answer (score 0):

Use Mark to Mark option by adding anchor points to all of the vattus. Refer this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=io56-xzCbms as guided by shankarsivarajan on github.